# Connection Manager Provider SSIS package in VS 2012

Tags: ssis

I am creating my first SSIS package using Business Intelligence in Visual Studio 2012. I am adding the contents of an Excel sheet to an local VS database. In the Destination Assistant I am asked Destination Type = SQL Server, New: Provider - I see no .NET Framework option. The result seems to be that I am then unable to select my server and therefore databases.
Am I just missing the point?

Comment: so whats the problem. what you explain it sound like you are missing .ner drives. ckeck for the drive please!!

Comment: Hi sorry bit of a noice to this. I am following the wizard provided by Business Intelligence in VS 2012. This asks for a Provider this defaults to Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0 but with this the server hosting my database is not visible for selection. I have tried all the list of providers it has, but still the same issue.

Comment: are you using NT or SQL user. do user that you use have right on the database. check the user permission or Use SA. this will eliminate security issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you investigate the destination server and verify that you have the providers installed on that system. Typically these are installed at the time that SQL server is installed, but is possible via custom installation to specify the providers that are installed. It may be necessary for you to install any providers needed. A second option would be to point to a database that you know that you can connect to, say a localhost sandbox or other tried database. That would help you to determine if it's server side or client installation issues.